# What is the best way to save iphone app settings?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, settings

I'd like to allow user to change the setting of app. But I am not sure where shall I save the configuration.

Is there any local space allocated for app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `NSUserDefaults` class for storing settings. It's all [documented](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).